# Force code extention not opening salesforce login page

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, visualstudiocode, visual, forcecode

I downloaded force code extension for visual studio code.
When I'm trying to connect to specific org he doesn't open salesforce login screen in order to log in to the org.

Is there any permission that needs to be given for visual studio?

What could be the problem? I've configured everything!

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed the Salesforce CLI (this isn't part of the things you can get from the VSC marketplace, you'd need to get this from Salesforce themselves)?

Comment: I downloaded salesforce CLI in this link: https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli
there is anything else?

Comment: Yes, the other part of my question was asking if you had also _installed_ the cli.

Comment: Yes I installed it, but its not working.. Do you have more ideas?